# How to force loading background images using SSL from another domain?

Tags: css

I have an online store and for performance reasons the images are on another domain. On secure part of the website we force **SSL connection**, but than **the background images are not displayed**. When I try to open the image itself in browser it asks me to accept the security certificate first. After that the image is there.

My CSS is simple as:

```
.some_class {
    background: url('//another_domain.com/image.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Is there any way to make browser display background images from another domain when SSL is active?

If I use strict protocol with url:

```
.some_class {
    background: url('https://another_domain.com/image.png') no-repeat;
}
```

than the images are not visible on non-secure pages.

If I use `http://` than the page is not secure any more.

Comment: Try with adding hardcoded protocol (http://).

Comment: Tried with `http://`, but than I lose SSL, looks like with `https://` it works, but have to check it.

Comment: Both domains need to use SSL

Comment: If I use `https://` than it fails on pages where SSL is not active. Looks like there is no solution for both cases. Maybe to include stylesheet on another domain?

Answer (score 0):

if your domain is `https://www.your_domain.com`, but use hardcoded protocol in css

```
.some_class {
    background: url('http://another_domain.com/image.png') no-repeat;
}
```

The issue is related to "mixed content" - HTTPS pages which have HTTP resources (images, scripts, etc) embedded.

The point of using HTTPS is to ensure that only the originating server and the client have access to the secured page. However, in theory it might be possible for this security to be compromised if HTTP resources are embedded - a server might intercept an unsecured javascript file and inject some code to alter the secured page onload.

Most browsers will indicate that a secure page has mixed content by altering the "secure lock" icon, either by showing the lock as open or broken, or by making the icon red (Chrome displayed a skull and crossbones for a short time, but they realised that this was a bit serious for the potential threat level).

If another_domain.com is your domain, then add SSL to that domain, may be this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I see images than, but I lose green secure bar in browser, which I need specially because the website is an online store.